# how to write my own signer

Tags: tezos-client, remote-signer

For a research project, I'm trying to implement my own signer, such that I can run `tezos-client import secret key ALIAS "http://..."` and then I can use tezos-client to transfer and tezos-baker to bake.

What API does my server need to implement in order for this to work? I've seen a few projects that intend to do this like https://github.com/tacoinfra/remote-signer and I'm trying to understand if the API they supply is what I need:

- POST /keys/<key_hash>
- GET /keys/<key_hash>
- GET /authorized_keys

Thanks

Comment: You can run tezos-client using `-l` and it'll show you all the http calls it makes to sign an op.

Comment: @utdrmac, thx. it helps but still doesn't show what tezos-client send and what it expects to receive.

Comment: So the problem is to find the hash preimage: the message which you are signing in order to create a valid, signed transaction that can be published to the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

I've got here the beginning of an answer, after reviewing the code for a few libraries like:

- [tezos-hsm-signer](https://gitlab.com/polychainlabs/tezos-hsm-signer)
- [tezos-azure-hsm-signer](https://github.com/lattejed/tezos-azure-hsm-signer)
- [remote-signer](https://github.com/tacoinfra/remote-signer)

I found that it's pretty simple and to implement the signer we need to create a server with the following routes:

- `GET /authorized_keys`

  Retrieve the public keys that can be used to authenticate signing commands. If the empty object is returned, the signer has been set to accept unsigned commands. (most signers I saw just return empty object)

  returns `{authorized_keys: [pkh]}`
- `GET /keys/:pkh`

  Retrieve the public key of a given remote key (=public key hash)

  returns `{public_key: pk}`
- `POST /keys/:pkh`

  Sign a piece of data with a given remote key

  receives: a string of bytes

  returns `{signature: Signature.encoding}`

> This should be checked as it seems that when signer gets a block (for baking) it expects a different signarture

My main problem right now is to sign the data.